# Using Button Popovers with bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, button, popover

i am using boostrap for a simple webpage. I am trying to place a butting at the very bottom row in the middle of the page. This is a popover button. However when i place this button, and i click on it to make the popover message appear, there is no popover box where the message should be in, the message just appears on my webpage and it just covers the page to the right, below is my html code:

```
<div class="row text-center contact-row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
                    Popover on right
                    </button>
                    <br>
                </div>
            </div>
```

and below is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
     $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()
    })
    </script>
```

My questions are:
1.) how can i place the button in the middle of the page ?
2.) how do i make the popover message appear within a popover message box and not on the page itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will ask you first and foremost to verify your js files and your css. 
Make sure you have imported the following:

1. `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">`
2. `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>` make sure this comes before any other Bootstrap files ( include JQuery before Bootstrap).

For example:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

3. To answer your first question: add a class container first around the whole thing

   ```
   <div class="container">
       <div class="row center-middle">
           <div class="col-md-12">
             <button>......</button>
          </div>
       </div>

   </div>
   ```

   in your css:

   ```
   .center-middle{
        min-height: 100%; 
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thabk you, it works now, with the class="row text-center" and i placed my jquery scrip import above the bootstrap as well. thanks alot

Comment: the pleasure is mine @James